# Identify faces in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11

I manager to detect faces and receive an array of [VNFaceObservation]. But now I need to identify these faces.
I've build my own mlmodel with photos of all people I want to identify and using the following default identification code to identify those faces.

```
if let prediction = try? self.mlModel.prediction(image: pixelBuffer) {
        predictionValue = prediction
}
```

Is that the right way to identify faces? like any other image classification?

Thank you.

Comment: I ended up by using OpenCV using Python on my server as it needs a high processing power.